# Data.table 1.9.4 prohibits column self-filtering; new methods?

Tags: r, data.table

In data.table-1.9.2 the following syntax was allowed:

```
dt[some_column == max(some_column)]
```

This allowed for nice, easy and fast filtering on the column itself.

Now on data.table-1.9.4 the following error is thrown running the same code

```
object 'some_column' not found
```

I have two questions.

1.) Why change this beautiful attribute?! It'd be nice of Matt Dowle to comment here.

2.) Does anyone have some clever solutions to replace this method? Something other than

```
new.var <- dt[, max(some_column)]
dt[some_column == new.var]
```

Regards,

K

Comment: 1. A reproducible example would help. 2. There've been [quite a few issues that've been fixed in 1.9.5 since](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/README.md), which are related to the new (experimental) automatic indexing feature (which can be turned off with `options(datatable.auto.index=FALSE)`).

Comment: @Arun thanks for the tips! Good to know it will return in 1.9.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last binary version on CRAN for Mac SL branch is 1.9.2 which is what I had, and as you say that is not a problem:

```
> d <- data.table(a=1:10)
> d[a==max(a),]
    a
1: 10
```

So I got the most recent CRAN source version 1.9.4 and compiled with these results after unloading pkg:data.table and reloading :

```
> d <- data.table(a=1:10)
> d[a==max(a),]
Error in `[.data.table`(d, a == max(a), ) 
  object 'CsubsetVector' not found
```

After restarting:

```
> d <- data.table(a=1:10)
> d[a==max(a),]
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'a' not found
```

After building 1.9.5 from source (Mac 3.1.2 SL branch) using the instructions [at Github](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) the problem evaporated:

```
> require(data.table)
Loading required package: data.table
data.table 1.9.5  For help type: ?data.table
*** NB: by=.EACHI is now explicit. See README to restore previous behavior.
> d[a==max(a),]
Error: object 'd' not found
> d <- data.table(a=1:10)
> d[a==max(a),]
    a
1: 10
```

Comment: Thank you for confirming 1.9.5 resolves this issue from 1.9.4, @BondedDust.